# How to hide navbar when when overlay appears

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using code from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp) 'Sidenav Overlay' I'm trying to create the same effect in Bootstrap. I have the .navbar-toggle floating left and the navbar-toggle still shows when the overlay moves right. Not sure how to hide the navbar-toggle when the overlay appears. First post, Thanks

CSS

```
 .navbar {
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.navbar-toggle a:hover {
    border: none;
    background-color: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-toggle" onclick="openNav()"> 
      <span class="sr-only" >Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Nav</a>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </header>
```

Javascript

```
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle we can use?

Comment: I've added it to github [link](https://zepzia.github.io/bootstrap-slideout-navbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add z-index as 99 instead of 1 to .sidenav class

```
.sidenav {
background-color: #111;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
width: 0;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will help you. Try this

```js
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mySidenav").toggleClass("activeclass");
});
$(".closebtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mySidenav").removeClass("activeclass");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 3px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sidenav.activeclass{width:250px;}
.sidenav{width:0px;}
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.navbar-toggle a:hover {
    border: none;
    background-color: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* On s
maller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-toggle"> 
      <span class="sr-only" >Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Nav</a>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this might help you ! [Here is the working example](http://codepen.io/Xeoncross/pen/zxyWeW)

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style media="screen">
      /*body { padding-top: 70px; }*/
      #connectLogo {
        height: 60px;
        padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
      }
      #logo {
        height: 60px;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
      }

      .share-link {
        line-height: 60px;
        padding: 0 1em;
        font-size: 2em;
      }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default NOnavbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed menu-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share hidden-xs pull-right share-link" aria-hidden="true"></span>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <img class="center-block" id="connectLogo" src="http://app.talkfusion.com/connect_r/images/title-videochat.svg" alt="">
          <!-- <div id="btnShare" style="display: none;"><img src="share.svg" width="22" alt="share"></div> -->
        </div>


<!--
        <button type="button" class="share-link hidden-xs pull-right">
          <span class="sr-only">Share link</span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
        </button> -->

      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $(".menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```